# Open iTunes when iPhone is connected on a Mac

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, macos

I remember that during the installation of iTunes (while I was upgrading it on my Mac) it asked if I want to install an application so that iTunes can be opened when my iPhone is connected. Initially I didn't want this so I answered "No". Now I want this behavior, but have no idea where that option is.

How can I get iTunes to start up when my iPhone is connected?

I tried disabling/enabling the option "Open iTunes when this iPhone is connected" in my iPhone's Summary page on iTunes, but it doesn't help. I believe it needs that application it wanted to install initally.

The option to disable auto sync was enabled in the settings, but now I disabled it.

Comment: Platform? (I'm assuming Windows.)

Comment: @Philip: oops forgot to include that... It's on a Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to System Preferences → Accounts, and view your Login Items. One of them should be
**iTunesHelper**.

**If iTunesHelper is missing from Login Items, here's how to add it**:

iTunesHelper is located inside the iTunes.app bundle, at

```
/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/iTunesHelper.app/
```

1. Navigate into the iTunes.app package; in Finder, Right-click iTunes.app and select Show Packaged Content to get inside it. <sup>(Or use Terminal to navigate and then open Finder with `open .`)</sup>
2. Locate iTunesHelper.app, and drag it to the Login Items pane.
3. Logout or even restart may be required for changes to take effect.

Whew, that was weird. I'm glad I got it added back too. :-)

(Alternatively you could reinstall iTunes, but the above is much quicker and easier.)

These forum threads were helpful:

- [How to prevent iTunes from opening when iPhone connected](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?p=513255#post513255)
- [iTunesHelper is gone in login items...](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-80005.html)

Comment: I believe that iTunesHelper is exactly the name of the app it wanted me to install. Unfortunately, I don't have it listed in that list (since I opted out of installing it).

Comment: @Senseful: Hmm, I removed it from my Login Items and now I'm trying to find out how to add it again — it doesn't seem self-evident where to find it! :) It looks like the helper comes inside the iTunes.app bundle: `/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/iTunesHelper.app/...`

Comment: @Senseful: I updated the answer, check if you can get iTunesHelper added now!

Comment: (If iTunesHelper.app is missing from within the iTunes.app bundle on your computer, then my best guess is that you'd indeed have to reinstall iTunes.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try turing the option on in the summary panel when you have your iphone selected under devices. Otherwise uninstall and reinstall probably will work. On windows you might have a registry entry but I have not dug around in there looking for itunes prefs.

Comment: I already tried the first option. I'm not sure I want to reinstall since I'm afraid it will delete an old backup of my phone. Would Apple even allow you to uninstall iTunes from a Mac? I always assumed they pulled a Microsoft/IE.